# How to access the values selected in the multiselect dropdown list in PHP?

Tags: php, multi-select

I am using [Jquery Multiselect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) to have a dropdown list box with mulitselect option. I am populating the dropdown with the data from MySql database. I was not able to pass multiple values to the php file in $_POST.

My HTML & PHP code for Multiselect DropDown.

```
   <form id="intermediate" name="inputMachine" method="post">

<select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration" multiple="multiple"> 
  <option value="1 WEEK" >Last 1 Week</option>
  <option value="2 WEEK" >Last 2 Week </option>
  <option value="3 WEEK" >Last 3 Week</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


    <?php
        //include '../db/interface/DB_Manager.php';
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "infinit") or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db("serverapp") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $query = "select id,name from rpt_shift_def"; //Write a query
        $data = mysql_query($query);  //Execute the query
    ?>
    <select id="selectShift" name="selectShift" multiple="multiple">
    <?php
    while($fetch_options = mysql_fetch_array($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
    ?>

    <option name="selected_ids[]" id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['name']; ?></option><!--Echo out options-->
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Here i'm populating Shift dropdown in Multiselect Dropdown. If i select more than one shift, i was not able to get all those selected values in php. instead i get only the last selected value.

i want to do something like this.

```
   $shiftarraycalc = array();

foreach ($_POST['selectShift'] as $key => $value) {
    array_push($shiftarraycalc,$value);
}
```

but its not working.

I have no idea how to get multiple values in $_POST.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modified name as array in select

```
<select id="selectShift" name="selectShift[]" multiple="multiple">
```

and did like this and it works

```
$shiftarraycalc = array();
$shift=$_POST['selectShift'];

if ($shift)
{
    foreach ($shift as $value)
    {
        array_push($shiftarraycalc,$value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this too.

```
<form action="ResultsDulith.php" id="intermediate" name="inputMachine[]" multiple="multiple" method="post">
    <select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration[]" multiple="multiple"> 
        <option value="1 WEEK" >Last 1 Week</option>
        <option value="2 WEEK" >Last 2 Week </option>
        <option value="3 WEEK" >Last 3 Week</option>
         <option value="4 WEEK" >Last 4 Week</option>
          <option value="5 WEEK" >Last 5 Week</option>
           <option value="6 WEEK" >Last 6 Week</option>
    </select>
     <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Then take the multiple selection from following **PHP** code below. It print the selected multiple values accordingly.

```
$shift=$_POST['selectDuration'];

print_r($shift);
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for a while and just needed to add the [ ] after the name in the select tag -- e.g. name="selectDuration[]"  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="hanu" name="hanu[]" multiple="multiple">
<option> one</option>
<option> two </option>
<option> three</option>
<option> four </option>
<option> five</option>
<option> six </option>
<option> seven</option>
</select>`
```

And The php code for this is

```
$res_hanu = array();
$hanu_new=$_POST['hanu'];
if ($hanu_new){
foreach ($hanu_new as $value){
array_push($res_hanu,$value);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$shift=$_POST['selectShift'];

if ($shift)
{
    foreach ($shift as $value)
    {
        $shiftarraycalc[]=$value;
    }
}
```