# php mutiselect dropdown which get data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I would like to create a multi-select drop down list of countries in my form which lets users choose more than one country and also provides the ability to remove the item they selected, if needed.

I could create a drop down list which extracts the name of the countries from a mysql table, but it lets users only select one country. I searched a lot for multi-select drop down but none of the samples that I have found get data from mysql. They had only a few options which could easily write with option value like [How to access the values selected in the multiselect dropdown list in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455715/how-to-access-the-values-selected-in-the-multiselect-dropdown-list-in-php)

This is my code through which only one item can be selected:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('imdb');

$sql2 = "SELECT country FROM countries";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

echo "<select name='country'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['country'] . "'>" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: uh, `<select name="country" multiple>` You browser couldn't care less where the options in the select came from. it just sees html.

Comment: @MarcB : thanks, I tested now it looks like multiselect, but still i cannot select more than one, I think because I have to use the $POST method.

Comment: no. a form doesn't care if it's being submitted via get or post. get just has some limits that post doesn't. for a simple form like this, there is no difference.

Comment: @MarcB: sorry, one more question: I wrote my php code inside html form, could you please tell me if I write it in a separate file, how can I call it from inside html?

Comment: @MarcB your comment should be an answer

Comment: @monamona: `<form action="yourscript.php">`

Comment: @MarcB: yes, but this form contains lots of questions of various types (checklist, dropdown, radiobuttons, etc). I dont know if I can write <form action ..> again after this specific question ?

Comment: Your question implies you don't know how forms work. you only output **ONE** `<form>` tag, and put ALL of your select/input/textarear/whatever form elements inside that single form.

Comment: @MarcB: u r right, this is my first experience with forms and php, .., however, this is what I have done till this point (I used only ONE form tag and put all others inside the form...), but for example, for one of my questions I used auto-competition for which I called it's function from inside html.. I thought I may be able to do something similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found what I was looking for. So I share it since might be useful for those with similar question.

First, as Marc said, I had to add multiple like below:

```
<select name="countrylist[]" multiple="multiple">
```

and this is the html line that I was searching for :

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>"> <?php echo $row['country'];?> </option>
```

where country is the name of the related field in my database.

it might be worth saying that in order to insert the result in database (e.g table name = "test", field name = "q5":

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "user name", "user password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db name") or die(mysql_error());

$q5 = implode(',', $_POST['countrylist']);
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {       
   $query="INSERT INTO test (q5) values ('". $q5 ."')";

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );

   }
?>
```

It worked for me and hope will be useful for others.